# How to return file data securely in PHP

Tags: php, ios, json, download

Bottom line question: What is the correct PHP so that I can include a binary data file in the json based response object?

I have an (iOS, though it shouldn't matter) app that's communicating with a server.  I want the server to return a file on successful login.  I do **NOT** want this file to be downloadable via browser or other means.  Hence, the file directory is protected from public-browsing.

I've got a file structure on the server that looks like this:

```
.../userFiles/
    myFile.zip
    yourFile.zip
    somebodyElsesFile.zip
    // all the other files, snip
.../server/
    login.php
    // other stuff, snip
```

`userFiles/` directory has `drwxrw----` permissions, and is the same owner & group as `server/`, so I *think* that part is right.

My server PHP code has:

```
// A bunch of stuff, snip.
// by this point, user is already verified valid login.
$filePath = "../userFiles/$username.zip";
if (file_exists($filePath))
{
    // get the user's file
    $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    if ($fileData)
    {
        $response->addparameters(array('data' => $fileData));
        $response->addparameters(array('DEBUG-filePath' => $filePath));
    }
    else
    {
        $response->addparameters(array('msg' => "can't read data."));
        $response->addparameters(array('DEBUG-filePath' => $filePath));
        $response->setStatusCode(500);
    }
}
else
{
    // deal with non-existent file, snip
}

$response->send();
exit();
```

When I login from my app, the response json looks like this:

```
myapp[13529:3615028] -[LoginViewController connection:didReceiveData:] ***** Login, but no data:
    {
        "DEBUG-filePath" = "../userFiles/olie.zip";
        data = "<null>";
        token = [token redacted];
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  More importantly: What is the correct PHP so that I can include a binary data file in the json based response object?

It shouldn't really matter (except that I'm using an app, not a browser, to access this API), but I'm running in iOS and my desired way to get the file data once this all works is:

```
NSData *zipFile = [json objectForKey: @"data"];
// unzip the file, deal with contents, snip.
```

Other info: My `$response` code is 200, and the `DEBUG-filePath` and `data` parameters give me a high degree of certainty that I'm on this particular code path (as opposed to some other failure, elsewhere.)

I'm fairly expert at iOS, but very new to PHP.  I managed to get upload & save the file to work, but am having trouble returning it on next login.

Any hints would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like typo:     $fileData = file_get_contents($farmFilePath); vs     $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);

Comment: No, that's just bad editing on my part.  Will fix.  (Sorry, I modified the original slightly, trying to remove all reference to "farm", since that's not part of the problem.  Looks like I missed 2, now corrected.)

Comment: Also, My response object is `$response = new Response();`; the original source is lifted directly from http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook .  I don't think the problem is there, since everything else about it works perfectly (and it's in use all over "everywhere" as an Oauth2 mechanism.)  Unless there's something weird where it doesn't properly-handle binary data.  I guess I don't know much about that end of things.

Comment: try base64 encoding content during transmission. e.g. $data = base64_encode($data);

Comment: if communication protocol is json, I am quite sure that binary data would not work directly, thus suggesting base64 encoding for transmission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try base64 encoding content during transmission. e.g. `$data = base64_encode($data);`

if communication protocol is json, I am quite sure that binary data would not work directly, thus suggesting base64 encoding for transmission.

Comment: Yup, that got me a whole bunch of data (rather then the previous NSNull object.)  I'm now dealing with "Unterminated string around character 198", but I'll either solve that on my own or ask a new question, later.  Thanks!

Comment: To save folks the few seconds to find the *other* SO answer, to get that data at the iOS end is: `NSData *zipData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: zipData64 options: 0];` (new in NSData as of iOS 7 :) )